# Bundle update is failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authlogic, bundle

I just ran `bundle update` and got the following error - I have no idea what this is.

`c:\San\ruby>bundle update
Updating git://github.com/odorcicd/authlogic.git
github.com[0: 207.97.227.239]: errno=No error
fatal: unable to connect a socket (No error)
An error has occurred in git when running git fetch --force --quiet --tags "git
://github.com/odorcicd/authlogic.git" refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*. Cannot complete bundling.`

All my gems are up to date (`gem update --system`) and installed (`bundle install`). I did just upgrade from Rails 3.0.0 to 3.0.1, which required some other updates for Activesupport, Activemodel, etc, also to 3.0.1. Do you know what might be causing the error above?

Comment: How about remove authlogic gem from your bundle file, and perform the update. Then put it back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first glance, this looks like a network error connecting to github.  Try to clone the repo via command line and see if you can get to it.  A proxy or firewall may be causing this issue.

```
git clone git://github.com/odorcicd/authlogic.git
```

Or you can try the http url instead:

```
http://github.com/odorcicd/authlogic.git
```